# Media Device (MTP) problem

Tags: settings

I have USB Debugging on, whenever i set the USB Computer connection to MTP it just disappear in the Devices list, I set to PTP and it appears in the Devices list, help please.

Comment: please add as much information as you can - e.g. your android version, the device you are using, when the problem first started and changes you have made befort, aswell as what have you tried to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its an incomplete question but will try to answer.
First of all make sure you installed your smartphones drivers successfully by enabling usb storage if available.
If its not available install from your smartphone manufacturer website or from xda developer website.

Then try to reboot your laptop and reconnect your smartphone with your laptop.

It will surely fix the issue.

Comment: Wait, how do I install drivers?  I connected my phone to my PC via USB, and selected MTP on the phone side, but nothing anywhere is prompting me to do anything.

Comment: Specify your device name. I will look into it.